# If statement not working after minimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll

I had an if statement inside a scroll function, to check if the div `#homepage-flag` or the div `#landingspage-flag` exists. It was something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if($('#homepage-flag').length > 0 || $('#landingspage-flag').length > 0){
      // code
    }
});
```

I minified the code, but now the if statement only works for the div `#landingspage-flag`:

```
$("#homepage-flag").length > 0 || $("#landingspage-flag").length > 0 && $(window).scroll(function(l) {
  // code
})
```

Comment: What minifier are you using? That looks completely wrong.

Comment: Wait, your saying the minified version is the second code snipplet?  Cause that's jacked up.  Side note: `if($('#homepage-flag, #landingspage-flag').length)` would work for an if instead of two conditionals.  Though it should also be said you should really avoid DOM lookups in a scroll event handler as it fires ALOT.

Comment: I used http://jscompress.com/. I have used it more times, and everytime it did well, till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minified code is completely wrong. The minified version should be something like :

```
$(window).scroll(function(g){$("#homepage-flag").length>0||$("#landingspage-flag").length>0});
```

Comment: Oh damn, very sloppy minify indeed. One question, where do I put my code?

Comment: The same place you'd put it if it wasn't minified.

Comment: $(window).on('scroll',function(e){if($('#homepage-flag').length>0||$('#landingspage-flag').length>0){//your code goes here}});

Comment: There is a difference between javascript minifier and jQuery minifier

be sure to use jquery minifier

Comment: What is the difference? jQuery is written with javascript, so why isn't a javascript minifier sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#homepage-flag').length > 0 || $('#landingspage-flag').length > 0){
  // code
}
```

will be:

```
if($("#homepage-flag").length>0||$("#landingspage-flag").length>0)//code;
```